# Why no results from this query?

Tags: dbase

This is my SQL query and 2 calculations, VAT and Total Cost no longer work. I have tried several adjustments, like adding or removing brackets, but nothing I have done works.

```
SELECT 
    "ID1", 
    "Date", 
    "KWH Used", 
    "Unit Cost", 
    "Standing Charge", 
    "No Days", 
    "KWH Used" * "Unit Cost" / 100 AS "Electric Cost", 
    "EPG", 
    ( "Electric Cost" ) - ( "EPG" ) AS "Cost after EPG", 
    "No Days" * "Standing Charge" / 100 AS "Total Standing Charge", 
    ( ( "Electric Cost" ) + ( "No Days" ) * ( "Standing Charge" ) / 100 ) * 0.05 AS "VAT", 
    ( "Electric Cost" ) - ( "EPG" ) + ( "No Days" ) * ( "Standing Charge" ) / 100 + ( ( "Electric Cost" ) - ( "EPG" ) + ( "No Days" ) * ( "Standing Charge" ) / 100 ) * 0.05 AS "Total Cost", 
    ( ( "Electric Cost" ) + ( "No Days" ) * ( "Standing Charge" ) / 100 ) * 0.05 AS "Total Cost" 
FROM "EONElectric"
```

I tried removing brackets and enclosing each part in brackets, reducing or removing a calculation, ie `*0.05`.
I was hoping for some kind of figure in the relevant box

Comment: When you say "no longer word" that means they worked before? What did you change? Can you provide your database schema and some data so the problem can be reproduced?

Comment: You haven't shown the definition of your table(s), without which it's hard to give a good answer.  See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)  Also, "doesn't work" is a very vague description - what results do you get, and how does that compare to what you expected?

Comment: There's no `WHERE` clause, so this should return a row of results for each row in the table. If you're getting no results, it must mean the table is empty. Are you getting an error instead? If so, post the error message.

Comment: Note that you can't refer to a column alias in the same SELECT list. So `( "Electric Cost" ) - ( "EPG" )` will try to access a table column named `Electric Cost`, not the value that was calculated 2 lines before.

Comment: You could use a subquery to calculate `Electric Cost` and then refer to that in the main query.

Comment: @Ada, yes the query did work upto last month. I created the said dBase last year and I got some help from here with it. I have not changed anything at all, only LM has been upgraded from 21.1 to 21.2. I have 3 tables : EONElectric , EONGas and FuelCosts. The same query for EONGas  works fine and does all the calculations. Obviously I changed the EONGas instances to EONElectric

Comment: @Barmar, No you are right, but neither is there a WHERE clause in another query for a different utility: gas, and that query does all the calculations I need. Also there is no error message when the above query is run. Just to point out, that I used Edit from the right click context menu to insert all the above information, and I thought that it would be easier to pot the sql query. Thanks

Comment: This is the VAT query in or for the EONGas which does the required calculation: ( ( "Gas Cost" ) + ( "No Days" ) * ( "Standing Charge" ) / 100 ) * 0.05, and this is the VAT query in EONElectric which does not do the calculation ( ( "Electric Cost" ) + ( "No Days" ) * ( "Standing Charge" ) / 100 ) * 0.05 Thanks

Comment: I have 21 records in the said query, and the calculations work fine for 20 of those records, but not for the 21st record. This was shown by me removing the calculation line?? , running the query and no data was shown nor calculated. I then re added the calculation line?? and ran the query again. This showed calculated data for the first 20 records only. Any ideas any one please.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you can't reference an alias in the same SELECT statement where it's defined. However, you can use a subquery or a common table expression (CTE) to achieve the desired result.

Here's an example using a subquery:

```
SELECT 
    "ID1", 
    "Date", 
    "KWH Used", 
    "Unit Cost", 
    "Standing Charge", 
    "No Days", 
    "Electric Cost", 
    "EPG", 
    ("Electric Cost" - "EPG") AS "Cost after EPG", 
    "No Days" * "Standing Charge" / 100 AS "Total Standing Charge", 
    ("Electric Cost" + "No Days" * "Standing Charge" / 100) * 0.05 AS "VAT", 
    ("Electric Cost" - "EPG") + "No Days" * "Standing Charge" / 100 + (("Electric Cost" + "No Days" * "Standing Charge" / 100) * 0.05) AS "Total Cost" 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        "ID1", 
        "Date", 
        "KWH Used", 
        "Unit Cost", 
        "Standing Charge", 
        "No Days", 
        "KWH Used" * "Unit Cost" / 100 AS "Electric Cost", 
        "EPG"
    FROM "EONElectric"
) AS subquery;
```

In this example, I introduced a subquery that calculates the "Electric Cost" separately, and then I reference it in the main query. This way, you avoid referencing an alias in the same SELECT statement where it's defined.

Please replace the subquery content with your actual calculations.

Comment: thank you very much for that and it works just as I wanted. It does all the calculations fine.